# How to see errors and warnings in WinEdt

Tags: errors, warnings

I am writing my thesis and I want to check my warnings and errors. How I can run pdf by command prompt ?

I want to see my errors and warnings.

Answer (score 4):

Did you say with winedt?. Here we go:

Go to `Options` → `Execution Modes`. In the window that opens choose `pdflatex` (or any other compiler of your choice. Check the boxes next to

```
Open Error Dialog
Open Warnings Dialog
```

as show in the next figure:

[image]

Now make a faulty code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\newcommand{\xrightharpoonupdown}[2][-10pt]{%
\stackunder[#1]{$\xrightharpoonup{\text{#2}}$}{$\xrightharpoondown{\text{\phantom{#2}}}$}%
}%


\begin{document}


\xrightharpoonupdon{but with longer harpoons}%    don should be down

\end{document}
```

Compile this with `pdflatex`. The error line will be highlighted with red. You can move to the next error using the arrows (which I marked with blue) in your console.

[image]

Comment: I tried this tutorial, but I don't got it